# DD-WRT router installation problems

Tags: wireless-networking, router, dd-wrt

I recently installed DD-WRT on my TP-LINK wr841n v9 router. The installation seemed to go fine, but the internet doesn't work. I can access the settings page at 92.168.1.1, and in my computer's network settings, it says I am connected to the internet and have an ip address. However, whenever I try to load a page, it gets stuck on the "resolving host" step. Is there some setting that is missing that's preventing the router from working? Here's a screenshot of the settings page: [image]

The numbers in the "gateway" and "local dns" field were originally 0.0.0.0. The internet didn't work, so I tried changing them to the values seen in the image (taken from my old router's configuration page), which still didn't help.

I used this firmware: http://dd-wrt.com/site/support/other-downloads?path=others%2Feko%2FBrainSlayer-V24-preSP2%2F
and followed these instructions: http://greggborodaty.com/installing-dd-wrt-tp-link-tl-wr841n/
but I also did the 30-30-30 reset before and after installing.

Edit 1:
I tried setting up the dns, but this did not solve the problem. I set the gateway and local dns to 192.168.1.1. Then I set static dns #1 to 68.94.156.1 (att dns), and the 2nd and 3rd to 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4. I got one webpage to load, but it is one that I've visited often, so it might've been cached. No other websites will load.

I am able to ping my router (192.168.1.1), but I cannot ping google.com or 8.8.8.8.

Comment: Did the Internet connection work before you installed DD-WRT? Did the router have any special configuration for your Internet connection such as PPPoE?

Comment: Yeah, the router worked fine before I installed dd-wrt, no extra configuration necessary. And in the instructions I followed, the guy used the exact same router I had.

Comment: Why does the LAN configuration have a gateway on the router? What device is 192.168.1.254?

Comment: Did you just flash DD-WRT? If so you might want to do a factory default before setting it up,

Answer (score 1):

Probably it is an issue with the dns. You already tried to change the local-dns to 192.168.1.1 ?
You tried to ping the gateway/router at 192.168.1.1 ?
Or tried to e.g. ping www.google.com or with IP ?

Sorry I couldn't comment so I posted this.
If it's a problem I will delete it.

Comment: I tried setting up the dns, but that didn't solve it. I can ping my router, but not google.com or 8.8.8.8 (see my edit above).

Comment: Maybe you have on the Router a section for maintenance, with ping and other tools ? How about the section of WAN ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to setup DNS. For local DNS, you can often use your router (192.168.1.1).

For DNS 1,2,&3, you can use your ISP (ask them), Google (8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4), OpenDNS (208.67.222.222, 208.67.220.220) or some other service. You need at least one configured in order to resolve names.

Also, your gateway is your router (192.168.1.1)

Comment: Thanks for your help! I tried setting up the DNS (see edit above), but that didn't seem to solve the problem. Is there anything else it could be?